# How can I escape a '.' character in a field's name in mongoose update operation?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, escaping

I have the following schema for storing user statistics:

```
const statisticsSchema = new Schema({
    month: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    stats: Schema.Types.Mixed
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Which I use to insert/update user statistics in the database using the `findOneAndUpdate()` method.
Since the 'stats' field in my schema is of type Types.Mixed, if any of the fields in the update object I pass to `findOneAndUpdate()` contains a '.' character, mongoose creates an unnecessary additional hierarchy in the database. How can I escape the '.' character and insert the name as is (with the '.')?